# How to create search and replace dialog box in codemirror?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I have been using codemirror textarea in my project. In this, search and replace [demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/search.html) I can get the feature of search and replace. But I need like [this](http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/editarea/exemples/exemple_full.html) dialogue box. I tried a lot but am unable to get as I expect.

codemirror.net/addon/search/search.js This is the js code I have customised so far.

```
var queryDialog = 'Search: <input type="text" style="width: 10em" class="CodeMirror-search-field"/> <span style="color: #888" class="CodeMirror-search-hint">(Use /re/ syntax for regexp search)</span><button onclick="findtest()">Find<button>'; 
function findtest(){ 
CodeMirror.commands.find = function(cm) {clearSearch(cm); doSearch(cm);}; }
```

This is what I have tried.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) What is your expectation? 2) Show a bit of the code you have tried

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little late to answer this question, but I've found this to work:

```
document.querySelector("#openSearch").onclick = function(){ editor.execCommand("find"); };
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually can you explain this code? Will this create a pop up search and repalce dialog box?which element of Id is `#openSearch`?

Comment: #openSearch is the ID of the element which you want the user to click to open the search dialog. It can be any element.

Comment: Will try it and let you know

Answer (score 2):

Obviously this question is fairly old now, but in case anyone else stumbles across it looking for an answer, I have written a replacement search addon for CodeMirror that looks and acts more like a traditional find/replace dialog.  The built in search is made that way for compatibility reasons - without the dialog addon it will fall back to the browser's alert and confirm implementations.  My addon does not do that, and uses a slightly modified dialog addon to the original.

## NPM Installation

The new addon is called `codemirror-revisedsearch`, and you can install it using npm like so:

```
npm install --save codemirror-revisedsearch
```

## Manual Installation

If you don't want to use npm, you can download the source from https://github.com/maloric/codemirror-revisedsearch.  You will also need to download the codemirror-advanceddialog addon from https://github.com/maloric/codemirror-advanceddialog.

Comment: do you have a demo to see how this looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Store editor instance in window something like

```
window.editor = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('myEditorElement'), options);
```

Then you can use it anywhere even in onclick event.

```
<span onclick="window.editor.execCommand('findPrev')">↑</span>
<span onclick="window.editor.execCommand('findNext')">↓</span>
<span onclick="window.editor.execCommand('replace')">Replace</span>
```

I have built a JSON viewer tool used Codemirror.

Use Ctrl + F or Cmd + F to show the search box

Check demo here [codeflexy.com](https://codeflexy.com/)