# Replace Comments (Single Line and Block Line) with "\n" in CodeMirror?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am trying to replace all the block line/single line comments with '\n'.

If my code is:

```
import java.io.*;
import  java.util.*;

// Read only region start
class UserMainCode
{
    public int someFunc(int input1){
    // some comment
    // comment2

}
/* some random text
some random text*/ 
}

the output should be: 

import java.io.*;
import  java.util.*;


class UserMainCode
{
    public int someFunc(int input1){
}

}
```

Is there any way to achieve this using some function of CodeMirror?

Comment: Are you asking for a technique within the codemirror IDE to search and replace, perhaps based on a regular expression? If so, maybe make that clear with an [edit]. If so, there are a few answers already. e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/26230365/1531971

Comment: actually, I wanted the comments to be removed. However preserve the lines on which the comments were written. Basically I had to preserve the line numbers therefore replacing with a regex wasn't working.

Comment: Search and replace with a newline? But, anyway, my comment was a nudge for you to make it clear in the text of the question what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.